# Build a searchbard where pasting any url will load the website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, axios

I am trying to build a Search Bar in React where pasting any URL example - `https://www.google.com/` would load the webpage below it, the request would be made using `Axios.get(url)  setHtmlString(response.data)`

**My Approaches**,

1. Tried doing Axios get request and used the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` attribute to set it with response.data which is the HTML File.
   *Example:* `<div className='w-full h-full' dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlString }} />`
2. Tried `srcDoc` attribute inside an iframe which is also set to Response.data which is a HTML File. `<iframe className='w-full h-full' srcDoc={htmlString} />`

But the problem is many elements are not loading correctly and the page loaded in not functional. [image]

Console is showing these errors. [image]
some Websites are also showing `error blocked by client, blocked by CORS policy.` [image]

Comment: Google "CORS proxy". You'll need that to get further. You'll still have lots of problems though. You might need to rewrite a lot of URLs in the response.

Comment: @TrevorDixon What could be recommended way to deal with this. Actually for the Use Case I would be only using Gradio Links. https://gradio.app/ which sends a ML Model running on Local.